# How do I grant permissions to remotely start/stop a service using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-service

We have a PowerShell script that restarts a service on another computer.  When we use PowerShell's built-in service control cmdlets, like so:

```
$svc = Get-Service -Name MyService -ComputerName myservicehostname
Stop-Service -InputObject $svc
Start-Service -InputObject $svc
```

We get this error back:

> Stop-Service : Cannot open MyService service on computer 'myservicehostname'.

However, when we use sc.exe, like so:

```
C:\Windows\System32\sc \\myservicehostname stop MyService
C:\Windows\System32\sc \\myservicehostname start MyService
```

the start and stop succeed.

The user doing the restarting is *not* an administrator.  We use subinacl to grant the user permissions to start/stop and query the service:

```
subinacl.exe /service MyService /GRANT=MyServiceControlUser=STO
```

**How come PowerShell can't stop my service but `sc.exe` can?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It turns out **I wasn't giving enough permissions with `subinacl`**.  The possible access values for the grant action are:

```
    F : Full Control  
    R : Generic Read  
    W : Generic Write  
    X : Generic eXecute  
  or any following values  
    L : Read controL  
    Q : Query Service Configuration  
    S : Query Service Status  
    E : Enumerate Dependent Services  
    C : Service Change Configuration  
    T : Start Service  
    O : Stop Service  
    P : Pause/Continue Service  
    I : Interrogate Service  
    U : Service User-Defined Control Commands
```

I was using **S** (Query Service Status), **T** (Start Service), and **O** (Stop Service).  **I also needed E (Enumerate Dependent Services).**  It appears that the PowerShell cmdlets need to look at dependent services when starting/stopping.

**Here's my updated `subinacl` command:**

```
subinacl.exe /service MyService /GRANT=MyServiceControlUser=STOE
```

If you don't want to download/use `subinacl.exe`, you can use PowerShell via the [Carbon](http://get-carbon.org) module's [Grant-ServiceControlPermission](https://get-carbon.org/Grant-ServiceControlPermission.html) or [Grant-ServicePermission](https://get-carbon.org/Grant-ServicePermission.html) functions.  (DISCLAIMER: I am the owner/maintainer of the Carbon project.)

Comment: Please mark this as your correct answer.  This was a huge help for me for the exact same issue :)

Comment: I've never heard of `subinacl` before. What a useful utility! Thank you for coming back to leave this information for the rest of us.

Comment: Works great in non-domain environment with Windows 2016 servers to control services on remote computers.

Answer (score 0):

The following command works as expected on my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.

```
Start-Service -InputObject $(Get-Service -Computer [ComputerName] -Name spooler)
```

Can you also try this one-off command to determine if that works, annd have you verified that the user is a member of a group that is a member of the Users group on the target servers?

Comment: Your snipped doesn't work for me.  Due to security requirements, I can't make the user a member of the Users group (or any built-in Windows group).