# Why does powershell -command "Restart-Service Tomcat6" fail when run from a Scheduled Task?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, scheduled-task

I get the following error in the Scheduled Task history when I try to run a task:

```
Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\Restart Tomcat" ,
instance "{264b4620-5f3b-6c5f-a6cb-1625a7fa57de}" ,
action "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE"
with return code 1.
```

The scheduled task is configured as follows:

- Name: **Restart Tomcat**
- User: **DOMAIN\tomcat.restarter**
- Triggers: **Daily 2AM Enabled**
- Actions: **Start a Program**:

  - Program/script: **`powershell`**
  - Arguments: **`-Command "Restart-Service Tomcat6"`**

When I launch a Command Prompt as **DOMAIN\tomcat.restarter** with:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\tomcat.restart cmd
```

And run:

```
powershell -Command "Restart-Service Tomcat6"
```

Then `echo %errorlevel%` prints `0` and Tomcat gets restarted.  This shows that the SDDL on the Tomcat6 service is sufficient for the purpose and that **DOMAIN\tomcat.restarter** can restart it.

If I change the scheduled task arguments to `-Command "'hello world'" > '%TEMP%\Temp.log'` I get `return code 0` in the Task History and `hello world` shows up in `C:\Users\tomcat.restarter\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp.log`.  This shows that the **Log on as a batch job** User Right is effective for **DOMAIN\tomcat.restarter**, that it can run Powershell and that it can write files.

### UPDATE: Further investigation

I created a restart.bat in D:\tomcat\bin and set the Program/script to `restart.bat`, arguments to `> "%TEMP%\Temp.log" 2>&1` and Start in to `D:\tomcat\bin`.

Listing of restart.bat:

```
powershell -Command "Restart-Service Tomcat6"
```

I get the following in `C:\Users\tomcat.restarter\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp.log` I get the following content:

```
D:\tomcat\bin>powershell -Command "Restart-Service Tomcat6" 
Restart-Service : Cannot open Tomcat6 service on computer '.'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Restart-Service <<<<  Tomcat6
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Restart-Service], InvalidOper 
   ationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Power 
   Shell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand
```

Why does `powershell -Command "Restart-Service Tomcat6"` fail when run from a Scheduled Task?

Comment: Can you try `powershell -Command "& { Restart-Service Tomcat6 }"`?  I had a similar issue scheduling my own items and had success with that.  I do not know why for certain, but I had to use to the `invoke-expression` operator for some reason.

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to try `-Command "& { Restart-Service Tomcat6 }"` as the arguments for the scheduled task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

My SDDL was incomplete.  I needed to add **SW** (EnumDeps) to the already added **LCRPWP** permissions in the SDDL.

## Long Version

Here is the (sanitized) version of my (broken) SDDL:

```
D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;LCRPWP;;;S-1-1-11-1111111111-1111111111-1111111111-1111)
```

The problem is in the last clause permissions:

```
(A;;LCRPWP;;;S-1-1-11-1111111111-1111111111-1111111111-1111)
```

The SID **S-1-1-11-1111111111-1111111111-1111111111-1111** is correct for the group **DOMAIN\Tomcat Restarters** that **DOMAIN\tomcat.restarter** is a member of.  That much is right.  The permissions granted (**LCRPWP**) are insufficient for **Restart-Service**.

For the **Restart-Service** Cmdlet to work it needs the right to Enumerate Dependent Services.  In SDDL this is **SW** (EnumDeps) in the SDDL string.  I had **LCRPWP** which allows QueryStat, Start and Stop.

The correct SDDL for Tomcat 6 for me is:

```
D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;LCSWRPWP;;;S-1-1-11-1111111111-1111111111-1111111111-1111)
```

The mystery is why Powershell could run **Restart-Service** from a runas Command Prompt, but not from the Task Scheduler.

I got the necessary revelation from reading @splattered bits answer to his own similar issue with **Restart-Service** at https://serverfault.com/a/357753/57073.

Answer (score 0):

Does the command require elevation?  Even if you have UAC turned all the way down, the scheduled task would need the check box for having elevated privileges.

Comment: Good idea. However, with "Run with highest privileges" checked the result is the same: "return code 1".

Comment: Have you tried redirecting the output to a text file?  Like -Command "Restart-Service Tomcat6 > c:\RestartTomcatOutput.txt" or somewhere the account would have access to?

Comment: I have, it creates an empty file.

Comment: I should have clarified.  The command does not require elevation.  I had granted privileges I thought were sufficient to the user in the Tomcat6 service's SDDL, but I missed "SW" (EnumDeps).

Answer (score 0):

I was going to add this as a comment but the code handling is horrid:

Can you add a few lines to capture some more info please?

```
$1 = Get-Service *tomcat*
Restart-Service $1
$1 >log.log
$error >>log.log
```

$error should output all the error information that has been generated in this session.

$1 will just show what it finds when it searches for the Tomcat service. just in case it can't see it for what ever reason.

Comment: This is probably paranoia, but I'd be worried about dragging in unintended services with `*tomcat*`.  This is especially risky since the next line immediately invokes Restart-Service.  It would probably be better to go step by step and log Get-Service `*tomcat*`.  Where would log.log end up here?

Comment: @AlainO'Dea You are correct about the Restart-Service being too wide ranging. If I were to do this on my own systems I would run it once and confirm exactly what the service name is, and specifically perform the Get-Service | Restart-Service against that name. The >log.log will save to the working directory of the script. You could easily put >C:\Logs\log.log instead, to define a location.